# Ask newbies if they want an email notification on a question

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, email-notification

Over at physics.SE, I've noticed many questions in the "unanswered" tab, which have excellent answers but aren't accepted. It could be for two reasons:

- The OP didn't get an answer in xyz days so they forgot about it
- The OP didn't realize that questions can be accepted.

I mainly want to address the first. Here's my proposal: When asking a question, a *new user* (one who has had nearly no activity) can get a little popup--the yellow type-- which asks him if he wants an email notification on receiving an answer on that question. I know that there are issues about spam; so I think that it should be limited to that question only, and the page should have a prominent "you have email notifications ON for this question. Do you wish to turn it OFF?"

For the second, I feel that a yellow popup "use this button to accept the answer" over the accept button (automatically opens on page load) should be enough; though I don't think that this is the primary issue.

Comment: Note that by "no activity"; I do not mean rep; I mean if the user has not recently done anything and has <100 rep.

Comment: AFAIK, unaccepted questions getting to know about them after some period of time by header popup, if user comes back to the site. Isn't it enough?

Comment: @om-nom-nom they have to be logged in..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When asking a question, a new user (one who has had nearly no activity) can get a little popup--the yellow type-- which asks him if he wants an email notification on receiving an answer on that question

This sort of exists:

[image]

---

> I feel that a yellow popup "use this button to accept the answer" over the accept button (automatically opens on page load) should be enough; though I don't think that this is the primary issue.

This popup can be annoying, but when you upvote an answer, you get a notification to accept the answer if it's helped

Comment: For some reason I don't recall either; but idk..

Comment: @Sathya Well, it's really quite simple really.. but this isn't the forum to be asking (about se(x))